# Flutter: Querying AWS AppSync

Tags: flutter, graphql, aws-appsync

I recently started using AWS AppSync & Flutter. I am having a bit of hard time to connect them with each other.

I am using graphql_flutter package and haven't been able to figure out how to use it for querying  purposes.

Here is my Code Snippet in question:

```
final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
              uri: 'https://myapi.xyz.com/graphql',
            );


            final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
              getToken: () async => 'Bearer ${globals.token}',  
            );

            final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

            GraphQLClient client = GraphQLClient(link: link, cache: InMemoryCache());

            QueryOptions query = QueryOptions(documentNode: gql(queries.getAll));

            var result = await client.query(query);
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error: 'await' can only be used in 'async' or 'async*' methods.
            var result = await client.query(query);
```

How can I make the whole thing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Future function while working with async methods. You can change your method like [this](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_bloc/lib/repository.dart):

```
 Future<QueryResult> getRepositories(int numOfRepositories) async {
            final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
              uri: 'https://myapi.xyz.com/graphql',
            );


            final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
              getToken: () async => 'Bearer ${globals.token}',  
            );

            final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

            GraphQLClient client = GraphQLClient(link: link, cache: InMemoryCache());

            QueryOptions query = QueryOptions(documentNode: gql(queries.getAll));

            var result = await client.query(query);

           }
```

You can read more about asynchronous programming from the [official documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).